# How can a postgres insert containing "where not in <table>" break a uniqueness constraint on that table?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, unique, psycopg2, postgresql-13

We have two tables, one containing a full list of appearances of URLs, the other containing a list of unique urls, as enforced an MD5 uniqueness index. Simplified DDL:

```
create table myschema.posted_url (
    record_id serial primary key,
    url varchar not null
)
;

create table myschema.unique_urls (
    record_id serial primary key,
    url varchar not null,
    record_added timestamptz not null default now()
)
;

create unique index unique_urls_md5 on myschema.unique_urls (md5(url));
```

The uniqueness constraint has been working as expected for millions of rows in both tables. We have a single (python) process that adds new appearances of urls to posted_url, and then immediately runs this:

```
insert into myschema.unique_urls (url) (
    select distinct url from myschema.posted_url where url not in (
        select url from myschema.unique_urls
    )
)
;
```

We got a single instance of failure:

```
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_urls_md5"
DETAIL: Key (md5(url::text))=(<myurlmd5hash>) already exists.
```

The commit flow is that urls from a single entity are added, then the unique urls update is done, then commit, then move on to the next entity. In the above case, the crash prevented commit of the posted_url record, **but the commit to unique_urls appears to have happened** i.e. the unique_url record is timestamped as just before the crash and the posted_url records are timestamped as of the next time the process ran (next day).

How is this possible?

- Something other process interacting with these tables? No - other processes only query. We even have checks in place to ensure we cannot run two of these processes in parallel.
- Ok, lets assume I'm wrong about the above and something else came in and added the unique record. Isn't it still impossible for the insert statement to fail in this way? Doesn't it take place within a single transaction, so if the hash wasn't in the unique table when it was selected from, it shouldn't be in there at time of insert?

Thanks very much, and apologies I cannot post more full code for data privacy reasons.

Comment: I'm going to say it is because your index defines `UNIQUE` as `md5(url)`, whereas the `NOT IN` is working on just `url`.

Comment: You think there may be a hash collision, where md5(url) already exists in the table but url does not? Interesting, looking now.

Comment: select * from myschema.posted_url where (md5(url::text))=(<myurlmd5hash>); this returns only one result that was present at the time (a second result was added later on but therefore seems to be irrelevant). Does your idea rely on two different urls sharing the same MD5 hash? Isn't that extremely unlikely?

Comment: `select * from` what table? Have you looked at `unique_urls` to see if `myurlmd5hash>` equals `md5(url)`?

Comment: What does `select distinct url from myschema.posted_url where url not in (select url from myschema.unique_urls )` return when run on its own?

Comment: You only wrote `<myurlmd5hash>` as a placeholder but the error message tells you what actual hash value is triggering the error. Have you tried to find in both tables the records where `md5(url) = 'the actual hash value from the error message'`? Surely, you will easily find the conflicting records, if any.

Comment: I can answer your very last question. If you do concurrently in 2 sessions a hardcoded version of your query such as: `BEGIN; INSERT INTO unique_urls(url) SELECT 'a' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT FROM unique_urls WHERE url = 'a'); COMMIT;`, 1 transaction will fail with the error message you got. Thid is easy to test manually if you wait before executing the `COMMIT`in the first session you start. Obviously, after the transation is committed, you can rerun the query as many time as needed, it will be successful and nothing will be inserted again which proves the issue is indeed the concurrency.

Comment: Cont'd: note that doing it in a transaction left open is not a necessary condition for the failure, but you will have a hard time making a manual test without one.

Comment: *Same MD5 hash? Isn't that extremely unlikely?* Yes it is, as shown by your statement *constraint has been working as expected for millions of rows in both tables*. But extremely unlikely is **not** the same as cannot happen. So how many rows does it take for it to become very likely? A few million perhaps. As an much experienced mentor once told me: "Keep in mind that at some point your job becomes the systematic control of miracles".